# Trying to open custom domain from another device to ubuntu apache2

Tags: php, apache, apache2

Using Ubuntu 22.04 as the machine. already changing the /etc/hosts and making new domain.com.conf on /apache2/sites-available/ already check the connection between my ubuntu and my other device. But still need open it with 192.168.1.7:8080 to open it from other device, not with my custom domain. How to fix this?(but can open it on my ubuntu with domain.com:8080)

/etc/hosts/

```
`
192.168.1.7 localhost
192.168.1.7 domain.com
192.168.1.7 www.domain.com
`
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com.conf

```
`
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.:8080>
ServerName www.bpguestbook.local
ServerName bpguestbook.local

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
`
```

Comment: _"already changing the /etc/hosts"_ - on the Ubuntu system? Then it affects DNS resolving for that system only. If you want your _other_ system to be able to resolve `domain.com` to that IP address - then you need to configure this _in_ that other system.

Comment: ohh so samething on /etc/hosts on another device? What if its not on linux  how to do that but in same connection?

Comment: If you cannot access the hosts file on the client system, you need to setup the domain name in a DNS (and the client system as to query that DNS).

Comment: can u give me an example to that. Sorry im new on this. edit: I already figure out client OS to change the etc/hosts but do i need to change the /etc/hosts to all device. Is there a way to all device can use the custom domain withput changing etc/hosts